# Laravel trying to retrieve ID of model but not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve the ID of a product when using the `findOrFail` method (`$product = Product::findOrFail($id)`). It successfully finds it and when echoing the contents of the product it looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"title":"Hoodie","description":"Lorem ipsum","price":"30","category":0,"images":1,"created_at":"2018-11-11 22:03:14","updated_at":"2018-11-11 22:03:14"}
```

And so I save it to a variable $product to access the variables. I'm able to call `$product->title` and it showing "Hoodie". However, when I try to call `$product->id`, it does not return anything?

I have no idea why this is happening so any help would be great!

`Product` class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Product extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    //table name
    protected $table = 'products';
    //primary key
    public $primarykey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'category', 'images'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category', 'id');
    }

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Images', 'id', 'images');
    }
}
```

And part of the the ProductsController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('product');
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        die($product);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your Product.php model class file and the controller capable of returning $product->title.

Comment: @TarekAdam I've edited the post

Comment: change die() to dd() and post the output please.

Comment: May I ask where the issue is occurring, and the code in that function?  Or is the issue in the destroy you posted?

Comment: @TarekAdam I've updated it, when I do dd($product->id) it retrieves the value fine but when I try to call it normally $product->id, it still provides null

Comment: Are you calling $product->id after delete()?

Comment: @J.A.Streich The issue is occurring when trying to retrieve $product->id in the destroy method, which was working last time I tested it out for some reason but now it returns null

Comment: @J.A.Streich And nope, I'm simply trying to retrieve it before delete()

Comment: Is this a RESTful resource?  or a manually added route?  I mean, exactly what does the form look like and where does it post?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest type-hinting a Product and passing in the object to be destroyed so that you have a RESTful resource like this:

```
public function destroy(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    $product->delete();
}
```

The difference is that you're not submitting the id via the form, your passing it in the URL you submit to.  It still has to be a post with a CSRF token, but the form shouldn't require a data field for the id.

Comment: I'm guessing they are trying to perform some logic on the object being deleted.  (And they should use an observer instead, but whatever.)

Comment: This way, they still get the object being deleted and can do whatever to it before deleting.

Comment: Agreed, route model bindings are great ~ not sure it solves his ->id problem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It turns out that for some reason, I just can't echo the $product->id but I can still call it and it retrieves the correct value.

Comment: Tarek, my guess was that he was trying to lookup the model from the $id but $id wasn't null (because it was passed to the function in the way he wasn't expecting (i.e. in the URL of the post and not in request->input).

user7162641, None of the code show you printing out the id, so can you post that code and where it happens so we can see what is really going on.  There is no reason an object field would suddendly become null because you tried to echo it.

Comment: In fact try my suggestion but instead of `$product->delete()` do `echo $product->id` and it should echo without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using resource `route` then your route URL should be something like this

http://localhost:8000/product/{id}

and your destroy method should only receive `id` instead of `Request $request` so you have to change your destroy method

```
public function destroy($id){
   $product = Product::findOrfail($id);
   $product->delete();
   return view('view.name',compact('product'));
}
```